# Displaying NavigationController from ActionSheet in TabBar app

Tags: ios

I new to iOS. Was developing on Android mostly. Currently took over an iOS app which I have to update with couple of features.

This app is TabBar based. Several navigation controllers are pushed into the tab bar which menages the switching between them. However now one of the tab opens an ActionSheet with couple of choices.

I have to open a new NavigationController on one of the ActionSheet button click.

Here is a fragment that defining which button was clicked:

```
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self openMyNavigationController];
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;            
    default:
        break;
}
```

I have no idea how should the openMyNavigationController method look

Started it like this:

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc ] nitWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navMyViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
```

What should I do to display the newly created NavigationController on the screen?

Comment: This will hide your TabBar or it will be in a tab and you put it into your navigationstack? Or you present it Modally?

Comment: I can't hide the tab bar. Action sheets should switch betwen navigation stack items if its possible. Or I could just present it modally? But how do I achieve that? I'm have a feeling that client recquires something oposite to native system approach, but I can't arrgue on that without a good reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I linked a new NavigationController to the tab item. I also open ActionSheet menu for that tab, which is basically what client wanted but from a user sight is ultimately stupid, since buttons to another ViewControllers should lay on newly opened tab... I hope the client changes mind.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I guess you need

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myViewController animated:YES];
```

to push new viewcontroller to your navigation stack.

But I think what you design for your application is wrong, well, is not iOS standard. Tabbar is not for "doing an action" like a button (I am also did some android project, but it is different. If you really want to do a button, you need to use tool bar not tab bar), it is for switching page. I think you need to read  [iOS User Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1). Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I've already gained some understanding and I agree that's not how the system works. Unfortunately the app was written badly from the begining by someone else, and I don't have time to refractor it completly. If there is any way that I could make action sheet buttons switch my view I gotta use that

Comment: How about this idea? when you click that tab and you will see one page which is contain four well styled button (may be like icons). And you click one of them to push view controller? Then everything is solved. Your action sheet is for pushing different pages right? : )

Comment: What if the tab that opens the ActionSheet holds the NavigationController with 3 items in stack. Is that possible to use action sheet buttons to switch between these items?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible. You can switch each view controller by action sheet. But I guess you need to take care about stack size, make sure that is not increasing by time. You can use – pushViewController:animated:
– popViewControllerAnimated:
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
– popToViewController:animated: combination to achieve that : )

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try and report with some code if success

Answer (score 1):

You can present that navigationController with a rootViewController modally:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated: YES];
```

Comment: self would be a viewController, perhaps the one you presented the actionsheet from.

Comment: I'm doing this: [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES]; but nothing happens

Comment: Do not call on the NavigationController, call it on the top viewController.

Comment: same result for [self.navigationController.topViewController presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

Comment: It should work on the correct viewController, but unfortunatelly I can't see your project in depth.